# Regex - Find which group is not matching the pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm quite new to regex and I'm trying to validate a file path to see if it matches my regex pattern, which represents the correct form of the file path.

This is the regex pattern:

```
string expression = (^P:)\\([A-Z]{3})\\(\d{6})\\(Revit)\\(Model)
```

And I'm matching it in my C# program simply by

```
Match match = Regex.Match(toCheck, expression);
```

Now this works with the correct folder path, such as *P:\SYD\121174\Revit\Model*.

But, if I input a path that is **almost** right, such as *P:\SYD\121174\ **Rhino** \Model* (difference in bold) I was hoping to get from the `match` object which group is wrong, so I could report it back to the user.
I tried something like this:

```
            foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
            {
                if (!group.Success)
                {
                    failingGroup = group.Index;
                }
            }
```

but then I understood that if the string isn't matching, then I don't get **any** group back.

Is there a way to get which group is not matching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex would become super long:

```
(?:(^P:)|[^\\]+)\\(?:([A-Z]{3})|[^\\]+)\\(?:(\d{6})|[^\\]+)\\(?:(Revit)|[^\\]+)\\(?:(Model)|[^\\]+)
```

Here is a more prettified version:

```
(?:(^P:)|[^\\]+)\\
(?:([A-Z]{3})|[^\\]+)\\
(?:(\d{6})|[^\\]+)\\
(?:(Revit)|[^\\]+)\\
(?:(Model)|[^\\]+)
```

Essentially, for each group, I added an alternative to match `[^\\]+`. This will match anything else other than a slash. So if the path says `Revi` rather than `Revit`, group 4 (`(Revit)`) would not match, but the second alternative, which is not in a group (`[^\\]+`), would. Now, the regex will still match even if one group failed, and you will have to check every group's `Success` to know if the path is the one you wanted:

```
var failedGroups = match.Groups.Cast<Group>().Where(x => !x.Success).ToList();
var success = !failedGroups.Any();
```

I personally don't like such a long regex, I would use a super permissive regex like this:

```
^([^\\]+)(?:\\([^\\]+)){4}
```

And check each group and [capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=netcore-3.1) in turn:

```
if (match.Groups[1].Value != "P:") {
    // Group 1 in your original regex is wrong!
}
if (!Regex.IsMatch(match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value, "^[A-Z]{3}$")) {
    // Group 2 in your original regex is wrong
}
if (!Regex.IsMatch(match.Groups[2].Captures[1].Value, @"^\d{3}$")) {
    // Group 3 in your original regex is wrong
}
if (match.Groups[2].Captures[2].Value != "Revit") {
    // Group 4 in your original regex is wrong
}
if (match.Groups[2].Captures[3].Value != "Model") {
    // Group 5 in your original regex is wrong
}
```

EDIT: You seem to want to allow a path with fewer than 5 components. You can just make the `{4}` quantifier into a `{0,4}` (even more permissive now), and check if group 2 has 4 captures:

```
^([^\\]+)(?:\\([^\\]+)){0,4}
```

```
if (match.Groups[2].Captures.Count == 4) {
    if (match.Groups[1].Value != "P:") {
        // Group 1 in your original regex is wrong!
    }
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(match.Groups[2].Captures[0].Value, "^[A-Z]{3}$")) {
        // Group 2 in your original regex is wrong
    }
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(match.Groups[2].Captures[1].Value, @"^\d{3}$")) {
        // Group 3 in your original regex is wrong
    }
    if (match.Groups[2].Captures[2].Value != "Revit") {
        // Group 4 in your original regex is wrong
    }
    if (match.Groups[2].Captures[3].Value != "Model") {
        // Group 5 in your original regex is wrong
    }
} else {
    // the path is shorter than expected
}
```

Comment: Great! I love this solution and it seems to be working well. There is only one thing I have noticed testing so far: if the length of the file path is different from the regex it doesn't capture anything. Let's say the path to be checked is P:\SYD\121174 it won't return anything. What I would like is to still match the beginning of the path (because it is matching) but then tell the user that a part of the path is missing. Is it possible?

Comment: @AndreaTassera See the edit I've decided to use a repeated group and use the `Captures` property to get the value of each repeated group, and also check how many times the group has repeated. .NET is one of the very few engines where you can do this :)

Comment: Love it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with regex groups, but it will be nice to demonstrate such validation 
 with almost only C#.
 You can use this function to detect the problem after you received no match from your full regex pattern.

Please see comments inside the code:

```
private string FindPathProblem(string path)
{
    // check path start with p:\
    if (!path.StartsWith(@"P:\"))
    {
        return "description of the problem in group1";
    }

    // issolate [A-Z]{3}
    string group2 = path.Substring(3, path.IndexOf("\\", 3
    
    // check the length is 3
    if (group2.Length != 3)
    {
        return "description of the problem in group2";
    }
    
    // check that all 3 characters are english chars
    Regex r = new Regex("[A-Z]{3}");
    if (!r.IsMatch(group2))
    {
        return "description of the problem in group2";
    }

    // isolate 6 characters (group 3)
    string group3 = path.Substring(7, path.IndexOf("\\", 7

    // check the legth is 6
    if (group3.Length != 6)
    {
        return "description of the problem in group3";
    }

    // check all characters are numbers
    int param = 0;
    var isnumeric = Int32.TryParse(group3,out param);
    if (isnumeric == false)
    {
        return "description of the problem in group3";
    }

    // check for the existance of Revit
    string group4 = path.Substring(14, 5);
    if (group4 != "Revit")
    {
        return "description of the problem in group4";
    }

    // check for the existance of Model
    string group5 = path.Substring(20, 5);
    if (group5 != "Model")
    {
        return "description of the problem in group4";
    }
    return "OK";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yeah that is one possibility that I initially implemented, but then I was wondering if it was possible with just regex for two reasons: 1. to see if regex was capable of it and 2. because I already had the necessary info in the regex pattern (i.e. it has to start with P:\, it has to have 3 upper case letters, etc) and I didn't want to duplicate the rules.

Comment: I would definitely go for the regex solution because it's more simple to maintain. just for general knowledge, manipulating strings without regex is less efficient but I guess that's not a "deal-breaker" in your project.

Comment: It shouldn't be as I am not changing/replacing the string, but just validating it. Thanks for your suggestion though. Much appreciated for the future